# Can you specify a different function signature on a child's implementation of a parent class' method?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm creating a repo module that contains very generic methods.  As long as each inheriting class has `tableName` configured, the base query for creating, finding, or deleting records is the same for all child classes.

I have an attempt at this (outlined below), but the TS compiler is throwing an error of:

```
Type 'Car' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Car'.
```

Here is an example:

```
// In base-repo.ts
class BaseRepo {
  static create<T>(columns, values): T {
    // This is just example - the real implementation is more secure
    return db.execute(`INSERT INTO ${this.tableName} (${columns}) VALUES (${values})`)
  }
}

// in car-repo.ts
interface Car {
  id: number
  make: string
  model: string
}

class CarRepo extends BaseRepo {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'cars'
  }
}

// in some other file
// I want this to automatically infer the type is `Car` based on some config in `car-repo.ts`
const carRecord = CarRepo.create(..., ...)

// ----------------------------

// This doesn't work, returning the error above:
class CarRepo extends BaseRepo {
  static create(columns, values): Car {
    return BaseRepo.create<Car>(columns, values)
  }
}

// This does work but it's far from ideal
class BaseRepo {
  static createRecord<T>(columns, values): T {}
}

class CarManufacturer extends BaseRepo {
  static create(columns, values): Car {
    return this.createRecord<Car>(columns, values)
  }
}
```

---

My hunch is that it's something to do with overwriting a parent method but the type signatures not being compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want something like:

```
class CarRepo extends BaseRepo<Car> {
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: No luck since these are static methods.  It looks like there's a proposal to allow this behaviour for abstract classes, but it isn't merged yet: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34665

Comment: I see. I think I ran into similar issues and just had factory methods outside my classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inheritance in your use case, it does not follow Liskov substitution principle. I would use a simple function like this:

```js
function create<T>(tableName: string, columns: any, values: any): T {
  return db.execute(`INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${columns}) VALUES (${values})`);
}

function createCar(columns: any, value: any): Car {
  return create('cars', columns, value);
}
```

If you really like using class + static method (which has no interest):

```js
class BaseRepo {
  static create<T>(tableName: string, columns: any, values: any): T {
    return db.execute(`INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${columns}) VALUES (${values})`)
  }
}

class CarRepo {
  static readonly tableName = 'cars';
  static create(columns: any, values: any): Car {
    return BaseRepo.create(CarRepo.tableName, columns, values);
  }
}
```